# SQL - create column with row averages excluding null values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

| name | jan | feb | march | april | may |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stan | 3 | null | 7 | null | 3 |
| dawn | 2 | 3 | 9 | 2 | null |

and I'd like to ad a column that has averages rows while skipping nulls

| name | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | AVG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stan | 3 | null | 7 | null | 3 | **4.3** |
| dawn | 2 | 3 | 9 | 2 | null | **4** |

The following code results in a null value for all rows that are missing values

```
SELECT *, AVG(jan+feb+mar+apr+may)/5 as avg
FROM t
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your table is not *normalised*. Have a column for *Month* and rows for each month then your query is easy using `avg()` - SQL works well with rows, not columns.

Comment: At a guess you would create a view and then join that to your other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `arrays` and then `unnest` it to calculate the `avg`

```
with cte as

(select  *, unnest(array[jan,feb,mar,apr,may]) as months
 from t)

 select name,jan, feb, mar, apr, may, avg(months) 
 from cte
 group by name, jan, feb, mar, apr, may;
```